# Android onResume update list adapter

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume

I'm using a list adapter to show different stores, when someone selects a store it takes them to a new activity where they can add the store to favorite on that screen.

There is a Back button on that calls `finish();` that goes back to the screen with the listview.

Now the problem is the listview isn't updated (ie. doesn't show that the store is added to favorite already). I tried this code but no luck:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    list.setAdapter(null);      
    updateMyList();
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, ((String[])names.toArray(new String[0])), 
        ((String[])status.toArray(new String[0])));
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

`updateMyList()` calls the server API and updates the names and status arrays.

With this code the list doesn't really update...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17333384/596555   ,may be help u

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should setAdapter in your `onCreate()` only, inside `onResume()` you just had to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` with the new collection of data. This will refresh your ListView with the new collection of data.

Answer (score 4):

Use this code:

```
myList.clear();
myList.add("your array list items");            
setListAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I think this will help you.

Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

First of all u need to add the list of stores to the arraylist,
submit this **array list** to the **ADAPTER** then add it to the list view

```
 list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

it will display the stores list; take `onListItemClick` click there u will get `listItem` Id; by using the list item ID u can give intent like this

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),------.class);
  startActivityForResult(intent);
```

Take a java bean /setter and getter methods class; take getter method as static, set the store name what you have created in the child activity; override method called `onBackPressed()`; inside of that method write

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

take a method `onActivityForResult()` in the parent class; inside of that method

```
 arraylist.add(javabeanClassname.getName());
```

add that arraylist to the `Adapter` and write the code

```
 list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score -1):

Before adding new View to listView remove all previous view

```
listView.removeAllViews();
```

and then add adapter class with new values. One thing make sure that your values are updated while you returning from second activity, and this code is calling.