# Android Studio - Method onResume another class

Tags: android, android-studio, onresume

I have a delete Button in a ListView, when I press the button it works!

My problem is that I would like to refresh the ListView by calling its `onResume` method. Please does anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: Have you seen these questions? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8997682/4236400 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/11686745/4236400

Comment: There's no onResume() in ListView, I'm sorry.

Comment: Refactor the code so that the refresh logic is outside onResume() on a separate method, and call that method on onResume() of the listview and your button onClick().

Answer (score 0):

OnResume() is only ued for Activities not for components .